# MySQL Batch Updates in C

Tags: mysql, c

Does MySQL's C API support batch updates? I'm writing an application where certain transactions are processed in large batches. It will grossly inefficient if in the logging process I wind up performing a single call DB for each insert.

Does C have anything similar to Java's APIs for batch SQL updates?

Thanks,

N.

Answer (score 7):

You have a few options to help speed up `INSERT` in MySQL:

- You can prepare a query and execute it with different values.  This has less overhead than preparing and execute a query for each row inserted.  See "[C API Prepared Statement Function Overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c-api-prepared-statement-function-overview.html)."
- You can insert multiple rows with one `INSERT` statement.  See "[INSERT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html)."
- You can execute multiple statements in one call with the API support.  See "[C API Support for Multiple Statement Execution](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html)."
- You should definitely use explicit transactions (assuming you use InnoDB) to avoid the overhead of starting and committing a transaction per row.
- There are other tips for improving speed of `INSERT` in "[Speed of INSERT Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-speed.html)."
- The greatest performance for bulk data loads is achieved through `LOAD DATA INFILE`.  This can be twenty times faster than using `INSERT`.  See "[LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)."

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is, even though there isn't any separate function for it. Take a look at:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html

You have to specify that [mysql_real_query()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-real-query.html) should parse multiple statements separated by ; in advance, by enabling a flag either when connecting or using [mysql_set_server_option()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-set-server-option.html).

```
mysql_set_server_option(&mysql, MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_ON);
```

This is how php implements [mysqli_multi_query()](https://www.php.net/mysqli_multi_query):

```
PHP_FUNCTION(mysqli_multi_query)
{
    // ...
    MYSQLI_ENABLE_MQ;
    if (mysql_real_query(mysql->mysql, query, query_len)) {
        // ...
        MYSQLI_DISABLE_MQ;
        // ...

        RETURN_FALSE;
    }
    RETURN_TRUE;
}
```

The MYSQLI_ENABLE_MQ macro evaluates to the code I provided above.