# multiple queries with mysql_query in a c++ project

Tags: c++, mysql, sql

So, this will not work with mysql_query.

I am strictly working with c++ and I am not using php.

I want this double query to be executed so that I will always have a unique ID in a transaction system with concurrent users creating IDs.

```
mysql_query(connection, \
"INSERT INTO User() VALUES ();  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); ");
```

It works in MySql DataBase perfectly, but I need to add it to Eclipse( I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS).

My application is quite big and I would not like to change to mysqli, if this is possible but if there is no other way it will be ok.

Can you help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does someone needs me to give a bigger snipet of code? I would gladly do that. Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Batch Updates in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667643/mysql-batch-updates-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the MySQL C API documentation:

> MySQL ... also supports the execution of a string containing multiple
> statements separated by semicolon (`“;”`) characters. This capability is
> enabled by special options that are specified either when you connect
> to the server with `mysql_real_connect()` or after connecting by
> calling `mysql_set_server_option()`.

And:

> `CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS` enables `mysql_query()` and `mysql_real_query()`
> to execute statement strings containing multiple statements separated
> by semicolons. This option also enables `CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS`
> implicitly, so a flags argument of `CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS` to
> `mysql_real_connect()` is equivalent to an argument of
> `CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS | CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS`. That is,
> `CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS` is sufficient to enable multiple-statement
> execution and all multiple-result processing.

So, you can supply several statements in a single `mysql_query()` call, separated by a semicolon, assuming you set up your mysql connection a bit differently, using mysql_real_connect.
You need to pass the following flag as the last argument: `CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS`, whose documentation says:

> Tell the server that the client may send multiple statements in a
> single string (separated by `“;”`). If this flag is not set,
> multiple-statement execution is disabled. See the note following this
> table for more information about this flag.

See [C API Support for Multiple Statement Execution](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html) and [`mysql_real_connect()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-real-connect.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will refer to C API support for extended inquiries. Kind regards.